# Linux based Steam games I have crash randomly

Tags: games, steam, crash

I hope I get all the required info here, I could really use some help.

Nearly every game that is linux compatible that I run through the steam client crashes with no error dialog popping up, they all might crash but I haven't played all of them enough to see it occur as sometimes I can get 2hrs of gameplay in before crash but usually happens between 10-45 mins.

I ran Steam from terminal and started Dying light until it crashed and have attached the terminal output.

I have reached out to Nvidia, Steam, and a couple of the games tech support both claim to be unable to recreate the error or get a usable error code to indicate what is going on from my logs and the tech support has never responded.

I have used psensor to confirm nothing is overheating, highest temp was the video card at 71c, however the graphics sensor shows in psensor reaching 100%, I have reduced graphics to the lowest they can be which seems overkill since I am running a 980, and the graphics still reaches 100%.

The only game I have that doesn't crash ever is Xonotic, however it does not run through the Steam client, I can play Xonotic for hours and it never crashes or has any issues.

My rig specs:

- I5-4690k
- 24gig ram
- Maximus VII Hero motherboard
- Geforce GTX 980 with 375.39 driver
- 200gigs free space on HDD
- 3 monitors 1080p(if that matters)
- Ubuntu 16.04 with all updates

The games it has occurred with

- Alien Isolation
- Bioshock Infinite
- Braid
- Dues Ex: Manking Divided
- Dying light
- Firewatch
- All of the half life games
- Mad Max
- Metro 2033 Redux
- Metro Last Light Redux
- Middle Earth Shadow of Mordor
- Portal
- Portal 2
- Sid Meier's Civ V
- Spider Rite of the shrouded moon
- The Swapper
- Team Fortress 2

[Here's the output from terminal](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24547947/)

Thanks in advance, I've been living with games crashing since I first got my video card, I have thought it might be faulty, but nothing else has the issue, even 4k video plays without issue( previously hooked up a 4k monitor to see if it could push 4k video) and I was previously able to play Far cry: Primal on windows for hours without issue on this pc, I just don't have any desire to use windows ever again and so will not be going back to it simply for gaming.

Please let me know what else I should provide and I will be glad to get it on here.

Comment: Big error logs can be posted at https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Not a problem, and will definitely do that in the future, do I need to edit this post with the link to the paste link or is it ok as it sits?

Comment: Revert to the graphics driver Ubuntu wants to use.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen That thing is terrible, is that a troubleshooting step or resolution?

Comment: @user664399 editing it would be the wise choice

Comment: @user664399 Terrible?  Does it work without crashing?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen actually it doesn't work at all because it doesn't support high enough level of opengl, and it also apparently doesn't support 3 monitors as it will not even show the third monitor in display settings, but thank you for the troubleshooting step.

Comment: Not the point.  The problem is identifying what component is doing the crashing, and the manually installed graphics driver is the main suspect.  Also note that Ubuntu may allow you to install an alternate graphics driver, as described in the answer from tatsu.  Have you considered using Windows if gaming is the most important to  you?

Comment: @ Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I never said that was the most important. I said it's been occurring since I got my video card, I've been able to solve any other issue I've had on my own, this is the only one I can't figure out. I hate windows firstly, and I use linux for everything else including work, so I won't setup a dual boot just for gaming, if something else wasn't working I might consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a new issue that you previously didn't have on ubuntu or are you a new ubuntu user?

Open up additional drivers (this is accessible from start amonst many other locations).

AMD could look like this :

[image: AMD Additional drivers]

(Nvidia : could look like this this or the last one should be your case) :
[image: Nvidia Additional drivers]

And either one could look like this :
[image: empty]

or just list intel driver as installed and nothing under the graphics section.

in any case if available the revert button is your friend and if not try one of the suggested options (you'll have to reboot each time to try the changes)

Comment: Well attempting to go back to nouveau was nothing short of a nightmare, after telling it to switch back in additional drivers it opened a new option where it claimed I had a manually installed driver(I hadn't that I know of), and after reboot I couldn't even get desktop, after trying everything I could find to manually install nouveau from terminal I finally gave up and reinstalled my OS, only to be informed that nouveau doesn't support opengl high enough to run Dying light, which is what I was testing with. Thanks for the help everyone, am I just stuck with nvidia's second rate product?

Comment: I'm not sure? maybe? nouveau isn't Nvidia's. I'm not clear on whether you've tried this yet : http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html

Comment: I have not, but I will definitely give it a shot. I've installed the drivers manually and used the additional drivers tool, but never added a ppa to get them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't add the repository and install the drivers that way, shortly after my last update, after an update to ubuntu and steam it simply stopped happening, and I am using the additional drivers option still. I'm not certain if the issue was OS or Steam based, but to whomever fixed the issue. Thank you. I have put in many hours of gameplay in my down time, it's freaking awesome and whomever fixed it, is like a superhero, that hasn't gotten the proper recognition.